# 301 redirect: Is this good or bad for 2 domains?

Tags: seo, google, 301-redirect, meta-keywords

Since i couldn't find any appropriate answer to my specific question, I wanted to ask you.

I've read alot of things about the 301-redirect for moving pages and so on. A customer of mine has booked a new domain last year for better search results (he included his main keyword into the domain. Before he had only a domain with his business name, which had nothing to say about what he does).

I told him, that he should do a 301-redirect so he doesn't lose his position on Google and to redirect all new customers coming from the old domain to the new domain.

After about one year where his site had a good amount of traffic, the results from Google  search for his keywords are getting worse and worse.
Since he didn't maintain his website (no new content, bad content on all pages and so on) I assumed this would be the problem.

He gave his website to another company which also makes websites. They told him, that this 301-redirection is very bad for his website.
They removed it, and also updated his content and the template, so now he has the same meta keywords on every page (instead of the specific ones I put there before).
He also removed the canonical-tag which I placed there to ensure no duplicate content.

What I am now afraid of is, that without this redirect Google now will find duplicate content and therefore kick him out of the index, which would be a nightmare, since most of his customers come over his website.

I need verification of the fact, that the 301 isn't bad but in fact the correct way of working with 2 domains. If possible with good sources I can point out to him since he don't wants to hear anything about this.

If someone also has a few words about the keywords and the canonical-tag I would really appreciate it!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your advice was good, the other company's advice is bad (as is common with those kind of companies). They should be using 301 redirects from the old URL to the new URL. The canonical tags are unnecessary since the 301 redirect will trump them but they don't hurt either and may catch accidental duplicate content within their website. [Google covers](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/12/handling-legitimate-cross-domain.html) [this well](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/reunifying-duplicate-content-on-your.html) so there is no ambiguous sources or possible misinformation.

The odds are they are going to run into issues with duplicate content. I bet the other company told them exactly what they wanted to hear and so they're running with it. I see it happen all the time. Feel bad for your friend but he's going to get what he deserves.

[FYI, the meta keywords tag has no SEO value at all](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html). So it doesn't really matter what is done with them.

Comment: So meta-keywords have absolutely no more reputation for search-engines? Good to know. As far as I knew, I thought they aren't the most important thing anymore but would still put into reference.
Thank you very much for your information and the link. I will tell him this.